# Database trigger to Insert same row to another db

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want to write a trigger so that when inserting to one table of database A the same row is  inserted into another table which belongs to database B. Database B has the same schema as database A

I created a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c6766) for my existing table structure

Comment: Are you trying to simulate database replication yourself?

Comment: i need to trigger "on insert" of one table same row to be updated to another table which keeps same schema of first table

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20379374/1316440) can help you.

Comment: Are you trying to keep 2 databases in synch? Any insert, update, and delete must be replicated to other one?

Comment: no..i just want sync only "INSERT"